# How to get parameters from this URL wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Normally it is working as expected, but while I was building my recover page it wasn't working as it should:

Url is:

```
http://localhost/recover/?email=example_email@email.com&key=936754fjh0983hf983jf45
```

And I am trying to get value of `email` with

```
$_GET['email']
```

but I'm not getting the email value.

I try this in function.php

```
add_filter(‘query_vars’, ‘parameter_queryvars’ );
function parameter_queryvars( $qvars )
{
$qvars[] = 'key';
$qvars[] = 'email';
return $qvars;
}
```

and this in single page :-

```
echo $wp_query->query_vars['key'];
echo $wp_query->query_vars['email'];
```

and not get me any value ?
I will be happy for any help :)

Comment: Are you sure you are on the correct page ? Try exit to see if you can stop the page ?

Comment: yes i sure and i try to `echo 'hi';` to this page and its print

Comment: Have you checked for php errors? 
`define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`

Comment: If you have this in the code `add_filter(‘query_vars’, ‘parameter_queryvars’ );` try changing the single quotes `add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter_queryvars' );` and in single.php use `get_query_var('key');`